# Zenburn for Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, themes

Is there a Zenburn theme for Netbeans?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try [Aloha color theme](http://blog.huikau.com/2008/04/28/aloha-color-theme-for-netbeans-61/) for Netbeans. It's similar to Zenburn.

UPDATE: for NetBeans 6.9 - [zenburn color scheme](http://forums.netbeans.org/topic29869.html)

Answer (score 5):

I had set one up manually for it, just like I did with a bunch of other editors/IDEs. Then eventually I just gave up and started using gvim for everything. Things are much easier now.

In all seriousness, when I was trying to do it for Netbeans, there seemed to be some limitations as to what you could change in the colors/syntax-highlighting. Though I don't recall specific examples offhand, there were a few things I couldn't get quite right, and it used to bother me.

If you want a color reference though, I have one on my wiki, for when I used to set up Zenburn in random editors, feel free to use it: http://wiki.steam-punk.net/zenburn

Answer (score 0):

Oh how I wish there was, however it is possible to change the colors manually.

Preferences > Fonts & Colors > Syntax